# Is there any means to resize bulk images?

Tags: image, image-processing, image-resizing, imageresizer

I have a load of image which has different sizes and dimentions, i have to resize every image within 500kb without loosing the aspect ratio of the each original image, resolution is not an issue. Could you suggest me a medium to do this task. Thank you.

P.S: I have to resize with respect to size of the image (within 500kb), not by dimentions or pixels

Comment: Are you asking what software can do such bulk-process images? This is a website for coding problems, not for software recommendations. There is no programming language specified in your post. And even if there was, please put some effort in yourself, and try to program something yourself first at least.

Comment: it worked like a charm.....how do I keep the png images without changing to jpeg

Comment: With JPEG, which is **lossy**, you can discard quality to decrease size - which is how the answer works. PNG on the other hand is **loss-less** so you do not have that option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your output images can be JPEG, you can use **ImageMagick** just in your Terminal. First, make an output directory, then recompress all your JPEGs, PNGs and BMPs like this:

```
mkdir output
magick mogrify -path output -format JPEG -define jpeg:extent=500kb *.jpg *.png *.bmp
```

---

If you are still using v6 **ImageMagick**, omit the word `magick` in the command above.

---

If, by *"load of images"*, you mean thousands, use **GNU Parallel**:

```
parallel -X magick mogrify -path output -format JPEG -define jpeg:extent=500kb ::: *.jpg *.bmp *.png
```

---

If, by *"load of images"*, you mean millions, use **GNU Parallel**:

```
find . -name "*.png" -print0 | parallel -0 -X magick mogrify -path output -format JPEG -define jpeg:extent=500kb
```